# How to parse this JSON response in Swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, response

I usually use this code to parse most of JSON responses

Before the code, here the JSON I need to get form it the "workspace"

```
{
    "count": 1,
    "next": null,
    "previous": null,
    "results": [{
        "id": 307,
        "email": "999@ios.net",
        "firstName": "fighter",
        "categories": [],
        "workspace": 302,
        "phone": "25485"
    }]
}
```

here is my code:

```
func getWorkSpace() {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        let returnAccessToken: String? = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "accessToken") as? String
        print("UserDefaults Returned Access Token is: \(returnAccessToken!)")
        let access  = returnAccessToken!
        let headers  = [
            "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
            "cache-control": "no-cache",
            "postman-token": "dded3e97-77a5-5632-93b7-dec77d26ba99",
            "Authorization": "JWT \(access)"
        ]
        let request  = NSMutableURLRequest(url: NSURL(string: "https://v5/workspaces/")! as URL,
                                           cachePolicy: .useProtocolCachePolicy,
                                           timeoutInterval: 10.0)

        request.httpMethod          = "GET"
        request.allHTTPHeaderFields = headers

        let session  = URLSession.shared
        let dataTask = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
            if (error != nil) {
                print(error!)
            } else {
                if let dataNew = data, let responseString = String(data: dataNew, encoding: .utf8) {
                    print("--------")
                    print(responseString)
                    print("--------")

                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        do {
                            let json = try JSON(data: data!, options: .allowFragments)
                            let answer = json["results"]
                            let workspace = Int(answer["workspace"].int!)
                        // let workspace = Int(answer["workspace"].string!)!
                        // let workspace  = answer["workspace"].int!
                            print("Workspace is: \(workspace)")
                        } catch {
                            print("Error saving workspace!")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        })
        dataTask.resume()
    }
}
```

This code usually works for me, but this time it's not. Please don't suggest me to use Codables because I didn't learn them yet.

Comment: `let answer = json["results"]` is an array, not a Dictionary. So `answer["workspace"]` won't work. Also, there is no need for `.allowFragments`, and instead of `JSON(data: data!`, use `dataNew` which is unwrapped).

Comment: Maybe your time is spent better learning using Codables instead of debugging JSON parsing you won't need once you know how to use Codables...

Comment: @Larme is right. Also, "Please don't suggest me to use codables because I didn't learn them yet." is probably the worst argument you could come up with. They are much, much easier and reliable than parsing JSON by hand.

Comment: Do not use `NSURL` and `NS(Mutable)URLRequest` in Swift. There is `URL` and `URLRequest` which is mutable as `var`iable. And don't dispatch the entire method to the main thread. `URLSession` uses its own background thread anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SwiftyJSON`

```
do {
    let json = try JSON(data: data1!)
    let answer = json["results"].array
    answer?.forEach {
        print($0["workspace"].int!) 
    }

} catch {
    print("Error saving workspace!")
}
```

`JSONSerialization`

```
let json = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with:data, options :[]) as! [String:Any] 
let results = json["results"] as! [[String:Any]]
results.forEach { 
     print($0["workspace"] as! Int)
}
```

`Codable`

```
struct Root : Codable {
   let results:[Model]
}
struct Model: Codable {
    let id: Int
    let email, firstName: String
    let workspace: Int
    let phone: String
}

let res = try! JSONDecoder().decode(Root.self, from:data)
print(res.results)
```

Comment: Sh_Khan You are always watching my questions :) THANKS!